# Copy and Paste a Named Range N times with modifications each time

Tags: excel, vba

I need to Copy and Paste a Named Range until there are N copies. N is defined by the value of a cell that the user can change.

```
For i = 1 To N
    NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'get the Next Empty Row
    ws.Range("B" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste
Next i
```

I am currently doing it with the above code, and it works fine for pasting the range at the bottom.
The main two things I am unsure of how to do are

1. I would like to modify the range slightly. The first row of each
   range, for example, says the copy #. It would have to increment by 1
   each time a copy is made.
2. I need to make sure there are N copies, if there are more than N currently, I would have to start deleting them from the end, I'm not too sure how to determine which cell range I would have to delete. If there are less ranges than the value of N, I would have to add (N - Current number of ranges) rows, but don't know the best way to determine what the current number of ranges is.

I asked a similar question regarding this problem a little bit ago but since then have gotten a better understanding of what it is exactly that I need guidance on so asking again.

I'm aware that there are plenty of similar questions that ask about copy and pasting a range, and my current solution is based off of those. None of the ones I could find show how to alter it slightly each time I paste though.

Comment: You already know the first row of each range - it's `NextRow`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a value from the worksheet:

```vb
Dim N as Long
N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Then you can use that value in your code, like as a parameter of the For loop:

```vb
For i = 1 to N
```

You can also use `i` or `N` inside the loop as values like

```vb
ws.Range("A" & nextrow).Value = "Copy " & i & " of " & N
```

Side Notes:

`Range.End` returns a range. So doing `.Row` and then using the row value to rebuild the range is circular and redundant. Your code can be simplified as

```vb
Dim nextCell as Range
Set nextCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
```

So with all of these pieces put together you get:

```vb
Dim nextCell as Range
For i = 1 to N
    Set nextCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    nextCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    nextCell.Value = "Copy " & i & " of " & N
next i
```

As for ensuring the worksheet only has `N` number of copies, no more no less. I would suggest wiping the sheet clean before pasting. This way each execution of the script will not need to worry about the number of previous copies.

You can use `Range.ClearContents` or `Range.Value = ""` to erase values only. To erase formatting you can use `Range.ClearFormats`. To erase both in a single line, you can do `Range.Clear`.

To clear an entire worksheet you can use `Worksheet.Cells` as the `Range`. For example the line `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear` would clear all values and formatting from Sheet1. If you wanted to preserve some rows or headers at the top of the sheet you could do `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("2:" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).Clear`. That line would skip the first row and clear everything on the other rows.

**In Response to your comment**

If you wanted to modify the current copies (Add or Delete) instead of wiping the sheet:

- To add a certain amount from a known current amount, you could do `For i = CurrentVal + 1 To N`.
- To delete from a current amount **down** to a desired amount you could do `For i = CurrentVal To N Step -1` . In this case, the `Step -1` tells VBA that the loop is meant to increment backwards from a higher value to a lower value.
- You would need an If/Else statement which checks if the code is meant to *Add* or *Delete* copies.
- To Delete the copies you would need some method of identifying the range of each copy on the worksheet.

Comment: I am not sure where the Copy# text is meant to go, so I just left it in the first cell of the copy range. I can update the code if you have a suggestion for where it would be better placed.

Comment: Each range has data that the user inputs, and calculates things based off of user inputted data. Because of this, I can't clear it as the data has to stay. Maybe I could store the data before I clear it, then readd it as I paste but I was thinking of just keeping track of how many ranges there are using a global variable and compare that to N to determine how many ranges to delete or add. I'm a bit stuck on determining how to get the last range, in order to delete it as needed. I'm thinking the logic is similar to determine where to add it, but with some tweaks.

Comment: Think I pretty much figured it out, slight issues with it still but should be pretty simple once I mess around with the code a bit more to figure out exactly what's going on. Thanks